# Why I can't capture the data when I added a new line?

Tags: regex

My regex:

```
^( *)((?:[*+-]|\d+\.)) [\s\S]+?(?:\n{2,}(?! )(?!\1(?:[*+-]|\d+\.) )\n*|\s*\n*$)
```

Data, match successfully:

```
* 2
* 3
```

Data, cannot match:

```
 <--- new line break here
* 2
* 3
```

Data, cannot match:

```
Hello <--- new line break here
* 2
* 3
```

Desired result for all three cases:
match:

```
* 2
* 3
```

Comment: Include empty line into the pattern...

Comment: So you would like the 3rd example to match or not? What is the desired result?

Comment: Rather than including empty line use `.*` if there can be other characters too.

Comment: @SchoolBoy updated the question, all the result should match with the first case.

Comment: What happens in case of `Hello\n* 2\nHello\n* 3`?

Comment: @SchoolBoy should not match, the `*` must be beginning of the line.

Comment: `\n` represents new line. So what happens when line 1: `Hello`, Line 2: `* 2` Line 3: `Hello`, Line 4: `* 3`

Comment: @SchoolBoy Sorry, I miss the `\n`. Line 2, Line 4 will be matched.

Comment: Do you know about the [multiline flag](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_m.asp)? F.e. `/^\s*([*+-])\s*(\d+)$/m` versus `/^\s*([*+-])\s*(\d+)$/`

Answer (score 0):

You should use the multiline flag. For the examples you have provided, the following regex would work:

```
/^[*+-] (.*)$/m
```

This will match any lines starting with `*`, `+` or `-`.